# SQL :Write a function to return value based on business rule

Tags: sql

I am trying to figure out the way in writing a function to do the following in the best possible way.

I need to write a function that will return me the exchange name. It will be referred in my view query below

```
select Exchange,ISIN,Investment_Codename,PROPORTION_NEWCASH,PROPORTION_MIDCAP,PROPORTION_SMALLCAP,PROPORTION_LARGECAP from FundPrice
```

Following are the rules of my function
1. If fund type=Listed Equity, AIM, Investment Company, Investment Trust, VCT or ETP and Update code=FinexDD/MM/YYYY
    should rturn  LSE

2. For anything else apart from the updatecode mentioned above with Fund Type = Listed Equity, need to take left two letters of the ISIN Code to indicate the country e.g. Microsoft=US5949181045, Michelin=FR0000121261 and infer the exchange name based on that

Comment: Tag dbms used. (Many products' stored procedures are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(CASE WHEN UpdatedCode <> 'LSE' THEN LEFT(Investment_Codename, 2)) AS [Country Code]
```

I think I understood your question. The above checks to see if UpdatedCode is NOT LSE, if it isn't it will take the Investment Code name, and present the first 2 characters. E.g. GB.